# How to execute tests in a test suite in parallel

Tags: python, selenium, python-multiprocessing

I have managed to run tests in parallel by using webdriver against a selenium hub and node. This code called before the tests is run.

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
   desired_capabilities={
        "browserName": "chrome",
        })

    cls.driver.maximize_window()
    cls.driver.get(cls.serverUrl)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=cls.driver.get(cls.serverUrl), args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

In that way I can start multiple browsers by executing them manually from Eclipse. However I would like to do that automatically in a testsuite. But in a test suite all tests are started in a sequence. If anyone has an idea how to proceed it would be great.

Comment: so this is more about a unit test library that supports execution of tests in parallel? [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org) can do that, using [`pytest-xdist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist) plugin. The other library that comes in mind is [`pulsar`](https://quantmind.github.io/pulsar/apps/test.html), although it is not a pure testing library. If this is what you are looking for, I can post an answer with an example of parallelizing tests with `pytest` since we use it quite extensively for testing of our django apps.

Comment: Yes that´s correct . We are using unit test and would like to execute the tests in parallel. So I can use the pytest library with the unit test framework?. Some example would be great thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## Preliminaries

I prepared some sample tests for playing with. These are some simple page title checks. We have one module `test_google.py` with two unit tests that check the titles of `www.google.com` and `mail.google.com`:

```
# test_google.py

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class GoogleTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


    def test_google_page_title(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.com')
        assert self.driver.title == 'Google'

    def test_gmail_page_title(self):
        self.driver.get('https://mail.google.com')
        assert self.driver.title == 'Gmail'
```

The second module is `test_stackoverflow.py` that contains one test that checks the title of `stackoverflow.com`:

```
# test_stackoverflow.py

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class StackoverflowTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


    def test_so_page_title(self):
        self.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
        assert 'Stack Overflow' in self.driver.title
```

Running the tests with the bare `unittest` runner yields:

```
$ python setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
...
running build_ext
test_gmail_page_title (test_google.GoogleTests) ... ok
test_google_page_title (test_google.GoogleTests) ... ok
test_so_page_title (test_stackoverflow.StackoverflowTests) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 11.657s

OK
```

## Migration to `pytest`

Install `pytest` via `pip`:

```
$ pip install pytest
```

`pytest` supports unit tests out of the box, so we don't need to touch the tests, we can run them immediately. Trying out the `pytest` runner:

```
$ pytest -v
================ test session starts ================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.5, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-47439103, inifile:
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                   

test_google.py::GoogleTests::test_gmail_page_title PASSED
test_google.py::GoogleTests::test_google_page_title PASSED
test_stackoverflow.py::StackoverflowTests::test_so_page_title PASSED

================ 3 passed in 13.81 seconds ================
```

## Running tests in parallel

This requires `pytest-xdist` plugin for `pytest`. Install it via `pip`:

```
$ pip install pytest-xdist
```

The plugin is installed now, but won't be active by default, so if you run `pytest` again, you won't notice any difference. Use the `numprocesses` key to parallelize the test execution. This denotes the number of processes that are reserved to run the tests, here I use the `auto` value to spawn as many processes as many CPUs my machine has:

```
$ pytest -v --numprocesses=auto
================ test session starts ================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.5, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-47439103, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.20.1, forked-0.2
[gw0] darwin Python 3.6.3 cwd: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-47439103
[gw1] darwin Python 3.6.3 cwd: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-47439103
[gw2] darwin Python 3.6.3 cwd: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-47439103
[gw3] darwin Python 3.6.3 cwd: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-47439103
[gw0] Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08)  -- [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
[gw1] Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08)  -- [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
[gw2] Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08)  -- [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
[gw3] Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08)  -- [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
gw0 [3] / gw1 [3] / gw2 [3] / gw3 [3]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling

test_google.py::GoogleTests::test_google_page_title 
test_stackoverflow.py::StackoverflowTests::test_so_page_title 
test_google.py::GoogleTests::test_gmail_page_title 
[gw0] PASSED test_google.py::GoogleTests::test_gmail_page_title 
[gw1] PASSED test_google.py::GoogleTests::test_google_page_title 
[gw2] PASSED test_stackoverflow.py::StackoverflowTests::test_so_page_title 

================ 3 passed in 7.81 seconds ================
```

You will see that all the three tests run in parallel by three chrome instances opened simultaneously. Each test runs in own process, so they don't interfere with each other. Also, notice that both test methods from the `GoogleTests` class also run in parallel, so this is not restricted to tests in different modules or classes.

## Integration with `setup.py`

When I first started the migration to `pytest`, one of the conditions I had was that the command `python setup.py test` should still work so we don't need to memorize an extra `pytest` command to run the tests and so we also don't have to adapt all our utility scripts or build jobs on our integration server, so here are the steps to update your `setup.py` script:

1. Add the following packages to test requirements:

   ```
   from setuptools import setup

   setup(
       ...
       tests_require=[
           'pytest',
           'pytest-runner',  # this one is needed to install distutils command for pytest
           'pytest-xdist'
       ],
   )
   ```
2. Add an alias to `setup.cfg`:

   ```
   [aliases]
   test=pytest
   ```
3. Add a configuration section for `pytest` in `setup.cfg`:

   ```
   [tool:pytest]
   addopts=--verbose --numprocesses=auto
   ```

Now, if you run `python setup.py test`, the correct runner will be invoked and the `xdist` plugin will be active by default.

## Additional notes

I personally really like `pytest` as it offers much more than a plain test execution - you can write tests as pure functions (no wrapping into `TestCase` classes required), collect tests without executing them, easily rerun only tests that failed recently, hook the code coverage measurement with multiple reports in different formats and many more. Refer to the [official docs](https://docs.pytest.org) for more details, it is really worth the reading time!

Comment: thanks a lot for great examples I will take a deep look into that.

Comment: Did you create a setup.cfg file and added it to the same directory as the setup.py file?

Comment: @AndersSundqvist yes, the file should be named `setup.cfg` and placed in the same dir as the `setup.py`. It ist optional though, we use ist only to hide all the command line args.

Comment: Actually what I have is a file test.py which contains a setupclass which is run before the tests and setup(self). I  don´t have a file with the exact name setup.py except for in a plugin folder.

Comment: Then you don't need the section at all, simply run `pytest -v --numprocesses=auto` in the project directory.

Comment: I tried that but apparently there is an error in the test.py which unit test ignores when running from Eclispe but pytest  stops. I don´t know if its possible to make it ignore errors.